# How use async/await without interrupting the Flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm just learning Kotlin Coroutines. And trying to understand `async/await` and `Deferred`. The problem is that in this example, in the `map()` block, the `Flow` waits for each async call. That's why I don't get all the data at once, but one by one with a delay of 1 second.

```
val dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + dispatcher)

val numbersFlow = flowOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    numbersFlow
        .map {
            val id = longTimeRequest1Async(it)
            val path = longTimeRequest2Async(it)

            Something(
                id = id.await(),
                path = path.await()
            )
        }
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .launchIn(scope)

    while (true) {
        //Just for program not finish
    }
}

suspend fun longtimeRequest1Async(value: Int) = withContext(dispatcher) {
    async {
        delay(1000L)
        value * value
    }
}

suspend fun longtimeRequest2Async(value: Int) = withContext(dispatcher) {
    async {
        delay(500L)
        "result $value"
    }
}

data class Something(
    val id: Int?,
    val path: String?
)
```

Is it possible to fill the `Something` fields with null values until `Deferred` is complete, and then fill with the calculated values without interrupting the flow?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "incomplete" instances of `Something`? It would usually be more idiomatic to make the 2 requests concurrent but emit a "complete" `Something` each time. If you really must start all processing at once, but then you should use `Deferred<Something>` rather than using nullable properties.

Comment: @Joffrey my application has a list that comes from the API fields are not initialized. Then I initialize the fields of each of the list items by calling suspend functions.
But I want to display the list with empty fields instantly, and replace placeholders with real values when loading.
Is it normal practice to store Deferred in model fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your supposedly async functions are actually synchronous, since `withContext` waits for its child coroutines to finish before it returns. The typical way to define an "async" function that returns a Deferred is to make it an extension function on a CoroutineScope, and don't mark it `suspend`. Suspend functions are usually expected to be synchronous.

```
fun CoroutineScope.longtimeRequest1Async(value: Int) = async(dispatcher) {
    delay(1000L)
    value * value
}

fun CoroutineScope.longtimeRequest2Async(value: Int) = async(dispatcher) {
    delay(500L)
    "result $value"
}
```

*You can also define them to not be extension functions and directly choose the scope they call `async` on, but that's not fitting for your example where the jobs should be cancelled if the flow is canceled.*

*Alternatively, you can make them synchronous suspend functions like in Louis Wasserman's answer, and push the choice to make them asynchronous to the caller. But then you probably should remove "async" from the function names.*

Now that's fixed, the easy way you can emit an object with null values followed by one with the asynchronously and parallel fetched values is to use `transform` or `transformLatest`. "Transform" is like "map" except you can emit multiple things or none at all depending on your logic. You can use `coroutineScope` to create a child scope inside the transform block to use for calling asynchronous functions. Like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    numbersFlow
        .transformLatest {
            emit(Something(id = null, path = null))
            coroutineScope {
                val id = longTimeRequest1Async(it)
                val path = longTimeRequest2Async(it)

                emit(
                    Something(
                        id = id.await(),
                        path = path.await()
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .launchIn(scope)
        .join() // Proper way to wait for job, although this infinite flow will never finish
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`longtimeRequest1Async` and `longtimeRequest2Async` are fundamentally broken the way you have designed them, and don't actually launch their work async at all.  `withContext` will not finish until all the subscopes within it, such as those started by `async`, have actually completed.

You must design them as follows:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runBlocking {
      launch {
        numbersFlow
          .map {
            val id = async { longTimeRequest1Async(it) }
            val path = async { longTimeRequest2Async(it) }

            Something(
                id = id.await(),
                path = path.await()
            )
          }
          .collect { println(it) }
      }

      while (true) {
          //Just for program not finish
      }
   }
}

suspend fun longtimeRequest1Async(value: Int) = withContext(dispatcher) {
        delay(1000L)
        value * value
}

suspend fun longtimeRequest2Async(value: Int) = withContext(dispatcher) {
        delay(500L)
        "result $value"
}
```